# CrafterCMS 3.0 - Getting error while trying to access delivery node

Tags: content-management-system, crafter-cms

I am getting following error while trying to run and access delivery node as per https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms#321-build-start-and-stop-a-specific-environment

```
org.craftercms.core.exception.StoreException: Root folder ./data/repos/sites/craftercms/ not found (make sure that it has a valid URL prefix (e.g. file:))
org.craftercms.core.store.impl.filesystem.FileSystemContentStoreAdapter.createContext(FileSystemContentStoreAdapter.java:59)
org.craftercms.engine.targeting.impl.TargetedContentStoreAdapter.createContext(TargetedContentStoreAdapter.java:75)
org.craftercms.core.service.impl.ContentStoreServiceImpl.createContext(ContentStoreServiceImpl.java:158)
org.craftercms.engine.service.context.SiteContextFactory.createContext(SiteContextFactory.java:249)
org.craftercms.engine.service.context.SiteContextManager.getContext(SiteContextManager.java:202)
org.craftercms.engine.service.context.SiteContextResolverImpl.getContext(SiteContextResolverImpl.java:65)
org.craftercms.engine.service.context.SiteContextResolverImpl.getContext(SiteContextResolverImpl.java:61)
org.craftercms.engine.servlet.filter.SiteContextResolvingFilter.doFilter(SiteContextResolvingFilter.java:39)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
org.craftercms.commons.http.RequestContextBindingFilter.doFilter(RequestContextBindingFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

These are the steps I followed

1. Built and started studio
2. Created a site made some changes
3. Published the changes
4. Built and started delivery. Delivery tomcat and Solr started fine
5. Went back to Studio and made some more changes and published
6. Went to http://localhost:9080/